# How to find the span of a set of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How do I find the span of a set of polynomials?
Specifically: $S=(1, x-3, x^2 +2x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mapping each polynomial to a standard basis vector. For example,

$$ 1 \mapsto (1,0,0)$$

and

$$ x \mapsto (0,1,0)$$

etc.

Then calculate the span as you normally would.